# Modifying Neural Network weights using estimators in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network

I need to modify the weight values during the execution, more specifically between the compute_gradients() and apply_gradients() functions. I was able to modify the gradients themselves, but i could not change the weights.

I'm using the tutorial for the Iris NN in tensorflow:
https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/samples/core/get_started/custom_estimator.py , the only difference being that i changed the minimize() function for the compute_gradients() and the apply_gradients() function.

```
grads_and_vars = optimizer.compute_gradients(loss)
// some way to change the weights
train_op = optimizer.apply_gradients(grads_and_vars, global_step=tf.train.get_global_step())
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi Lucas, welcome to SO! If any of the replies below answered your question, according to the way this site works, you would upvote/mark as answer one or several replies below. If your question was not answered, please provide more details by either commenting or editing your question.

Answer (score 0):

My best guess is that you are looking for `tf.assign` (from [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/assign)) to assign values to your `Variable` tensors.

According to the docs:

> Update 'ref' by assigning 'value' to it.
>
> This operation outputs a Tensor that holds the new value of 'ref' after the value has been assigned. This makes it easier to chain operations that need to use the reset value.